# Python3 Openpyxl - PatternFill bgColor not working?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I can't get the background colour to show up for patterned fills in openpyxl.

Here's my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill

wb_test = Workbook()
ws1 = wb_test.active

ws1["A1"].fill = PatternFill(patternType="lightVertical", fgColor="808080", bgColor="000000")

wb_test.save("wb_test.xlsx")
```

The `fgColor` attribute works perfectly, but `bgColor` is not doing anything.
Here's what the result looks like

[picture showing a coloured foreground and white background in cell A1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stNF5.png)

I'm using openpyxl version 2.5.9 and Python 3.6, which is the default on google colab

Appreciate your help!

Comment: openpyxl does the same here as Excel and you can check by comparing the files. For completeness, however, you should always use RGBa values prefixed with "FF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `openpyxl` is treating RGB HEX `000000` as white when a `patternFill` other than `solid` is used, weird bug. You can use `000001` to get the same effect youre looking for though (Black background).